# how to disable formcontrol select and form control in angular

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using angular material, I have implemented input and select form feilds and I have used form control to capture input and done some validation, but the problem is I am not able to disable form feilds.

I have tried this:

```
          select  = new FormControl('');
          input = new FormControl('', [Validators.minLength(3), Validators.maxLength(40)]);

          test(){
           this.select.disabled()
           this.input.disabled()
           }
```

even I have used disabled it is not working can anyone help me this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

formControl can be disable by disable method like this :

```
controlName.disable();
```

More details about disable form control is at this link : [how to disable form control](https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110)